# Change file in Git from Git LFS to a normal Git file

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I am trying to remove a `.txt` file that was being previously added as Git LFS.

In efforts to do so, I tried the following:

- `git lfs untrack "*.txt"`
- `git add "*.txt"`

And pushed changes. Still pushes files as LFS.

When I do `git lfs uninstall`, I get the below message:

```
Hook already exists: pre-push

    #!/bin/sh
    command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/pre-push'.\n"; exit 2; }
    git lfs pre-push "$@"

    Hooks for this repository have been removed.
    Global Git LFS configuration has been removed.
```

And my `.gitattributes` file has the following:

```
    *.xlsx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    *.txt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

I tried manually removing the contents of the `.gitattributes` file above and pushing again, but still no luck.

I even tried git `lfs migrate export --include="*.txt" --everything` but it would not allow me to push changes.

**My current state**: One .txt file is present as LFS file in GIT. I want this as a normal Git file.

Note: The file is a `requirements.txt` file, and is not a large file.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way, but I just renamed the file twice. If you have multiple files you can move everything into a sub directory and then back. This fixed it for me after removing `git lfs` and the `.gitattributes` file.

Don't forget to commit after each rename/move.